Android Studio. Ошибка Incompatible magic value
Android Studio на ровном месте начал выдавать ошибку когда создаешь новый проект Empty Activity
Incompatible magic value 1431524691 in class file org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/zip/UnsupportedZipFeatureException
Так же пишет что Gradle project sync failed

За что дизлайк? За тупой вопрос?

Попробуйте пересобрать gradle:
gradlew --recompile-scripts

второй вариант - укажите в build.gradle модуля совместимость Java:
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

